# how to filter users by multiple assigned license using ms-graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run a Microsoft Graph query to list all users who have with a M365EDU_A3_FACULTY or M365EDU_A5_FACULTY license assigned to them. This is what I'm running;

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(u:u/skuId eq e97c048c-37a4-45fb-ab50-922fbf07a370 or 4b590615-0888-425a-a965-b3bf7789848d)
```

But I get this error;

```
"message": "Invalid filter clause: A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Boolean' and 'Edm.Guid' for operator kind 'Or'.",
```

Can anyone assist in what I should be running here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `or` between two `any` operators.

When you use `assignedLicenses/any` twice in the filter, it will work only if you add `$count=true` to the query and you need to add `ConsistencyLevel` header with value `eventual` to the request.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(u:u/skuId eq e97c048c-37a4-45fb-ab50-922fbf07a370) or assignedLicenses/any(u:u/skuId eq 4b590615-0888-425a-a965-b3bf7789848d)&$count=true
```

[Advanced query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http)